# I keep getting nonce is too low when using truffle to call functions on contracts even though this works fine on remix.How can I fix this

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-invocation, nonce, kovan

I keep getting the nonce is too low when running functions with sub transactions on the kovan test net is there a way I can stop this from happening?these sub transactions are making transactions with other contracts.

For example

```
function randUseCount(testContract UseNum) public returns (uint){
    randomResult = randomResult% (UseNum.userCountView())+1;
    return (randomResult);
}
```

Where testContract is the contract it's calling.
This works perfectly on remix and I'm using the kovan test net.

Comment: sounds like for some reason your wallet is not aware of the amount of transactions you have previously made. What are you signing your txs with? is it metamask or another piece of software?

Comment: I'm running them straight from the truffle console by calling their functions for example
instance = await RandomNumberConsumer.deployed()
instance.getRandomNumber

Comment: I haven't worked with Truffle. I do Hardhat, but when that happens in the local blockchain, you have to go to metamask, and click the circle on the top-right corner "account" then settings -> advanced -> reset account -> reset. Maybe try that and let me know. Also, make sure you don't have network conflicts, like kovan and local host.

Comment: The nonce is the count of your transactions and therefore is unique per tx. So, for some reason, your wallet haven't counted some of your txs and therefore the network is letting you know that the nonce of that tx has already been used "too low". Check how many txs you have in Kovan, and the correct nonce of your deployment should be that amount (it starts from 0). If you can set it manually, that would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you're using that same wallet somewhere else. Web3 keeps an internal note of the nonce, and it internally increments it once it makes more transactions via the Web3 script. If you use that same wallet somewhere else (i.e., another Web3 script or in Metamask), that internal nonce would go out of sync with the real nonce that is needed to propagate that transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the contract not having enough funds to carry out a function that I asked it to carry out .

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using truffle console and fixed it:

> `instance.method(param1, param2, { nonce: YOUR_ACTUAL_NONCE })`

After this the nonce is back on track. 
Probably it works in the same way, when executing the script.
By the way, simplest way to find your nonce is too check the latest transaction of the account on a blockexplorer.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue with hardhat, it worked by resetting my account in my wallet, in case its metamask simply go to settings > Advanced > Reset Account